# Удачой или удачей

Tags: орфография, склонение, окончания

> Он был доволен своей удач..й.

Как правильно: удачой или удачей?

Есть правило, что в окончаниях существительный *под ударением* пишется о. Но в этом случае гласная не под ударением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно "удачей" (недостачей, задачей, порчей...), но "каланчой", "парчой", "саранчой"... Из этого видно, что для слов, оканчиваюшихся на -ча, окончание определяется наличием (здесь второй случай) или отсутствием (первый случай) ударения на последнем слоге у существительного в именительном падеже. Аналогичную закономерность можно заметить напр. для слов, оканчивающихся на -жа (поклажей, маржой), -ша (ношей, душой), -ца (царицей, пыльцой).